# Mysqlfrm can't connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

My server is set up with MAMP and I am trying to access to a .frm file via --server, it returns this error message: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (61 Connection refused)".

This is my input:

mysqlfrm --diagnostic wp_posts.frm  --server=root:root@localhost

Comment: This is an English language site. Please either post in that language or ask at [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com) instead.